# Add checkmark image to ImageButton on click

Tags: java, android, xml

this is my project:

[image]

when I touch one picture in each row I want something like this:

[image]

This is what I have in my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="android.goparty.rayoruiz.gopartyandroid.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/choises_title"
    android:id="@+id/choises_title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="500px"
    android:layout_height="600px"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/choises_title">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="109dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/bottomlist"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="109dp"
                android:id="@+id/houseParty"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:background="@mipmap/houseicon"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@android:dimen/app_icon_size" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="109dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:id="@+id/clubParty"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@mipmap/nightclubsicon" />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="109dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/bottomlist"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="109dp"
                android:id="@+id/drink"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:background="@mipmap/drink"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@android:dimen/app_icon_size" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="109dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:id="@+id/nodrink"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@mipmap/nodrink" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ok, I have the opacity setting alpha attribute.

```
public void onClick(View v){
   int[] array = new int[2];
   houseParty.getLocationOnScreen(array);
   **houseParty.setAlpha(new Float(0.50));**
 }
```

How do I get the picture of the button to change on click?

Answer (score 0):

You could swap the image of the ImageButtons when you detect a click using `setOnClickListener`. Here is a possible implementation:

```
ImageButton houseParty = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.houseParty);
houseParty.setTag(0); // We associate 0 with not pressed
houseParty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Change image. 
        if(houseParty.getTag()==0){
            houseParty.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.house_party_checked));
            houseParty.setTag(1); // Now button is pressed

        } else {
            houseParty.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.house_party));
            houseParty.setTag(0); // Now button is not pressed
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for that answer but I don't want to have a clone of each img, because there ir around 15 rows with 2 or 3 img, it will be heavy.

Comment: @CristianRuiz but even a single check mark has to be another img, so by layering one on a button would result in potentially n*2 images displayed simultaneously (n= number of buttons).

Comment: @CristianRuiz In both cases you still have to put in your drawables n*2 resources but if instead you swap the button image with one that is checked you won't have n*2 imageviews, but only n, which will result in theoretically better performance in runtime.